# send Rating via email form

Tags: php, forms, email, rating

I'm building an email form. In this email form, there is a star rating with radio buttons:

```
<span class="star-rating">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="1"><i></i>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="2"><i></i>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="3"><i></i>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="4"><i></i>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>
```

If I send the form to my email address, it shows me the star rating empty.

Here is the code to get the rating:

```
$rating = $_Post['rating'];
```

And this is the full code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email']) or isset($_POST['first_name']) or isset($_POST['last_name']) or isset($_POST['subject']) or isset($_POST['message']) or isset($_POST['rating'])) {



    // Mediatube Contact Informations

    $email_to = "info@mediatube.ch";

    $email_subject = "Contact to info@mediatube";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||

        !isset($_POST['message']) ||

        !isset($_POST['rating'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      

    }


    $email = $_POST['email']; // required

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required

    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $rating = $_Post['rating']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($message) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Email sent by Email Form at Mediatube.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }


    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Rating: ".clean_string($rating)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?>



<!-- html success code -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

What is wrong, what can I do?

Thanks for your replying!

Comment: There is no such thing as `$_Post` unless you created yourself.

Comment: Change $_Post to $_POST, change the name rating to rating[] and you cant have multiple elements with the same id so change them aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of mistakes in our code.

You can't have multiple ids with same name so you have to change this.

Also your code

```
 $rating = $_Post['rating'];
```

change to

```
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Upper case POST as i think it is case sensitive.

```
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
```

Assume that these inputs are correctly wrapped in a form which is being posted to a seperate PHP page just `echo $rating;` and ensure you have the correct value. Can find more on PHP POST Function [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Also unrelated - as @Pwner added. You shouln't have multiple elements with the same ID, to style these you should use CSS Classes. Learn more on ID vs Classes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: I assume your form is set with `method="POST"` ? Then `var_dump($rating);` on the page your form is posted to and let me know the response.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer was correct or led you to fixing your code please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this code

```
$rating = $_Post['rating'];
```

to this code

```
$rating = $_POST['rating'];
```

Now it works :)